# How to see if a file is imported from another file or run as the entry point?

Tags: elixir

I'm an Elixir newbie coming from Python. This would be the equivalent of `if __name__ == "__main__"`. Does this exist in Elixir/Erlang?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't be sure I'm understanding your question correctly but I think what you're looking for is [`Kernel.function_exported?`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#function_exported?/3)

You'd do something like

```
function_exported?(:main, your_func, your_funcs_arity)
```

For example,

```
function_exported?(:Kernel,function_exported?,3)
```

Kernel functions should always be available so you shouldn't normally need to specify the Kernel portion of the function name.

Hope that helps.